# Error when trying to add buttons to Discord JS interaction.reply

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I am currently having an issue with adding buttons to my Discord JS project, I am using Typescript and Discord JS v14 to make the bot.

My current Issue is with adding buttons, it gives me a long error that I am unable to find a solution on myself and I haven't found one online.

And yes everything has been included and everything is working on the bot, I am just receiving errors when trying to add buttons.

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
return interaction.reply({
    content: `There was an error while running the channel command. Please try again later. (${error})`,
    ephemeral: true,
    components: [new ActionRowBuilder({
        components: [
            new ButtonBuilder({
                customId: '1',
                label: 'yes',
                style: ButtonStyle.Success
            })
        ]
    })]
});
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Coby/Documents/GitHub/franksbot/src/commands/chanell.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2769",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 2, '(options: InteractionReplyOptions & { fetchReply: true; }): Promise<Message<boolean>>', gave the following error.\n    Type 'ActionRowBuilder<AnyComponentBuilder>' is not assignable to type 'APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent> | JSONEncodable<APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent>> | ActionRowData<...>'.\n      Property 'type' is missing in type 'ActionRowBuilder<AnyComponentBuilder>' but required in type 'ActionRowData<MessageActionRowComponentData | MessageActionRowComponentBuilder>'.\n  Overload 2 of 2, '(options: string | InteractionReplyOptions | MessagePayload): Promise<InteractionResponse<boolean>>', gave the following error.\n    Type 'ActionRowBuilder<AnyComponentBuilder>' is not assignable to type 'APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent> | JSONEncodable<APIActionRowComponent<APIMessageActionRowComponent>> | ActionRowData<...>'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 79,
    "startColumn": 26,
    "endLineNumber": 87,
    "endColumn": 15,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 267,
            "startColumn": 3,
            "endLineNumber": 267,
            "endColumn": 7,
            "message": "'type' is declared here.",
            "resource": "/c:/Users/Coby/Documents/GitHub/franksbot/node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I have tried many different approaches to this such as storing them in a variable first, I've tried different formats such as using .setStyle etc.

I expected it to not return an error and allow me to add a button to my message reply on discord.

Answer (score 6):

In TypeScript you need to specify that your `ActionRow` will contain `ButtonBuilder`.

You need to use `ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>` instead of just `ActionRowBuilder`

So with your example it would give:

```js
return interaction.reply({
    content: `There was an error while running the channel command. Please try again later. (${error})`,
    ephemeral: true,
    components: [new ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>({
        components: [
            new ButtonBuilder({
                customId: '1',
                label: 'yes',
                style: ButtonStyle.Success
            })
        ]
    })]
});
```